# Trying to name a file using template literal

Tags: google-apps-script, template-literals

I am trying to use a template literal to name a created Google doc using cell data in a Google sheet. This is the code that I found,

const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy('${row[1]} + KeyTags' , destinationFolder)

but it the file created is named this: "${row[1]} + KeyTags"

any changes I make are greeted with syntax errors...

I have been fighting this for hours!!!!

Answer (score 1):

To use a template literal, you surround the code in single backticks, not string quotes:

```
Correct: `${row[1]}KeyTags`
Incorrect: "${row[1]} + KeyTags"
```

Edit: You don't need to use `+` to concatenate strings when using template literals. My mistake.

Comment: @UebelhorDetail
My apologies, i made a small error. I edited my answer to solve it. When using template literals, you don't need to use a `+` to put strings together

Comment: SO my new code (const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(` ${row[1]} KeyTags `, destinationFolder)) generates a syntax error    Syntax error: Illegal character. line: 30 file: MAKEDOCS any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe revise you question to include the latest code and use a code block to distiguish from question.  Insert your code, select it and the press Ctrl+K.